# Stuck in trailhead - Quick Start: Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, trailhead

I am not able to display name of the contacts. It gives me a blank list. Here is my code:

```
<ul>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact1" >
<li class="minli"><h3>{!contact1.name}</h3></li>

</aura:iteration>
</ul>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getContacts");
        console.log('action-->'+action);
        action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
            console.log('Inside action setcall back');
            console.log('data-->'+data.getReturnValue());

        component.set("v.contacts", data.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**ServerSideController:**

```
public class MyContactListController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Contact> getContacts(){
         List<Contact> lstContacts =  [Select Id, Name,Email,Title,Phone from Contact LIMIT 10];
         system.debug('lstContacts-->'+lstContacts);
         return lstContacts;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full component code? Also check the state of the response and make sure it is a success before setting the attribute

Comment: Overall your code looks fine. Does the `getContacts` returns the contacts properly ? What does the debug log prints out for `lstContacts` ?

Comment: @Praveen: Yes it returns me 10 records with name,id of contacts

Comment: Did you declare aura:attribute contact as contact [] (array) or just contact?

Comment: @Rao: I have declared it as an array of contact

Comment: Got my silly mistake. I have used name instead of Name field. Now it is displaying name.

Comment: Can you post the full component for us please? How are you calling myAction method, through init handler?

Comment: Lightning is case sensitive :)

Comment: @Jill_sfdc Can you please answer the question and accept it yourself so that we can close the question

Answer (score 1):

Lightning is case sensitive. I used Name field instead of name field.